# PhantomJS on CentOS 5.5 (glibc and libstdc++ versions)

Tags: centos, centos5, glibc, phantomjs

I'm trying to run PhantomJS on CentOS, but I get the following:

```
./phantomjs: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by ./phantomjs)
./phantomjs: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by ./phantomjs)
./phantomjs: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by ./phantomjs)
./phantomjs: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /home/bamboo/bamboo-data/xml-data/build-dir/PHANTOMJS-ARTIFACT-JOB1/target/checkout/dists/linux_x64/bin/../lib/libQtGui.so.4)
./phantomjs: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by /home/bamboo/bamboo-data/xml-data/build-dir/PHANTOMJS-ARTIFACT-JOB1/target/checkout/dists/linux_x64/bin/../lib/libQtGui.so.4)
./phantomjs: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found (required by /home/bamboo/bamboo-data/xml-data/build-dir/PHANTOMJS-ARTIFACT-JOB1/target/checkout/dists/linux_x64/bin/../lib/libQtGui.so.4)
./phantomjs: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.10' not found (required by /home/bamboo/bamboo-data/xml-data/build-dir/PHANTOMJS-ARTIFACT-JOB1/target/checkout/dists/linux_x64/bin/../lib/libQtNetwork.so.4)
./phantomjs: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found (required by /home/bamboo/bamboo-data/xml-data/build-dir/PHANTOMJS-ARTIFACT-JOB1/target/checkout/dists/linux_x64/bin/../lib/libQtCore.so.4)
```

I even built a static build of PhantomJS, but it appears that the libraries bundled with PhantomJS have dependencies on glibc and libstdc++.

Building a specific PhantomJS binary on CentOS is not an option because this machine is our continuous integration box that builds and tests our project. I have PhantomJS packaged as an artifact which is then unpacked during the build process and used (for Javascript Continuous Integration). So this exact artifact needs to be used.

Is there an easy way to upgrade glibc and libstdc++? I tried `yum install glibc` and `yum install libstdc++`. I noticed that it did perform an update, but there was no change after I tried to run PhantomJS again.

Answer (score 2):

You built PhantomJS on a much newer system than the one you're trying to deploy it on. Rebuild it on a system matching the deployment system.

Comment: The PhantomJS artifact needs to be the same across all systems (dev and build). I tried building PhantomJS on CentOS and it built fine and it even seems to run fine. However, when I copy the binaries and libs over to my box and run that build of PhantomJS, I get `./phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libQtWebKit.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` which makes no sense to me because those libraries are there in the `lib` sub directory. They just need to be placed relative to the binary in `bin`.